# Make cryptsetup prompt at boot time ignorable

Tags: boot, encryption, luks

I have a machine with multiple users. Home directory for one user is encrypted with LUKS. There is a crypttab entry for opening the LUKS partition at boot time.

When the system boots up, it asks for the encryption passphrase.

There are other users on the system who do not have their home directory encrypted. How do I allow booting the system up with opening the LUKS partition only optionally?

I would like other users to be able to skip entering the passphrase.

If you press `Esc` or `^D` at the prompt, the system goes into emergency mode. I would like it to continue booting normally instead.

OS `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

Kernel version `5.15.0-58-generic`

Mounted partition structure is below:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=a5f0521f-070e-4319-b7d4-d13a6f8de6ec /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=0786-63C0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
/dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt/win ntfs rw,relatime 0 1
/dev/mapper/docs /home/dmitry ext4 rw,relatime 0 1
```

Here's the crypttab

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab
docs /dev/nvme0n1p9 none luks,discard
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1453609/edit) and include the distro and version of Linux you are using. Also include the partition structure of the SSDs//HDDs. It is not clear if the whole `/home` is in a separate partition or the `/home/james_bond` is in a separate partition. Or you used some other means to encrypt the special user's home folder. Add all these information to your question. Copy and paste the content of the file `/etc/fstab` into your question and format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Try commenting out the last line of `/etc/fstab`: that is, put a `#` in front of the line `/dev/mapper/docs /home/dmitry ext4 rw,relatime 0 1`. The reboot. This will not mount the encrypted folder at computer start/reboot. And therefore will not ask for the LUKS password. I don't know if you will be able to login as the user `dimitry` after that. Update your question with what happens when you try to login.

Comment: The above will probably not work, as the user `dmitry` won't be able to login.